# Передача данных вперед с одного ViewController в другой через TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Имеется фейково-загрузочный VC, в который я загружаю данные с Firebase. Передавались в MyCarVC напрямую, но я решил добавить TabBar. Как мне передать данные в  MyCarVC, который теперь в TabBarController'e как на схеме ниже, учитывая что он находится в другом Storyboard? Заранее благодарен!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]`
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

```
    let serverManager = ServerManager()
    serverManager.downloadcars(for: userID!) { [weak self] cars in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.cars = cars
        
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            
            let myCarVC = self?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MyCarViewController") as? MyCarViewController
            myCarVC?.titleCar = cars.modelName + " " + cars.models[0]
            myCarVC?.modelName = cars.modelName
            myCarVC?.model = cars.models[0]
            myCarVC?.year = cars.year[0]
            myCarVC?.engineType = cars.enginesType[0]
            myCarVC?.engineDisplacement = cars.enginesDisplacement[0]
            myCarVC?.body = cars.body[0]
            myCarVC?.transmission = cars.transmission[0]
            myCarVC?.mileage = cars.mileage
            self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(myCarVC!, animated: true)
        }
        
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так, например:

```
guard let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController, let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers else { return }
if let nc = tabBarViewControllers.first as? UINavigationController {
        let myCarVC = ...
        nc.pushViewController(myCarVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: В консоле выдает ошибку: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "userID" at /cars to your security rules for better performance. Гугл подсказал то нужно поменять правило в Firebase на   {
"rules": {
    "data": {
      ".indexOn": "date",
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
  }
} В консоле теперь пишет Listener at /cars failed: permission_denied

Comment: Может что-то нужно изменить в классе? http://joxi.ru/52apyLDUgXxg7m

Comment: В общем-то ответ был на вопрос, как передать данные через TabBarController :). Дело не в классе, вам нужно вначале добиться, чтобы приходили данные из Firebase, а затем уже парсить их и передавать в нужный контроллер.

Comment: Просто добавление TabBarController`a начало выдавать ошибку в консоле, всe норм парсилось и передавалось до него((

Comment: Попробуйте откатиться и проверить, что всё работает.